# Adding an image to a custom cell subview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
  CGRect nameValueRect = CGRectMake(80, 5, 200, 15);
            UILabel *nameValue = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:
                                  nameValueRect];
            nameValue.tag = kNameValueTag;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:nameValue];
            [nameValue release];
```

...

```
 NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NSDictionary *rowData = [self.computers objectAtIndex:row];
    UILabel *name = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:
                                kNameValueTag];
    name.text = [rowData objectForKey:@"Name"];
```

This code is from a tutorial that I'm using which creates a subview within the cell to add some text.

However, what I want to do is instead of adding text I will place an image.

I tried UIImageView *posterValue = [[UIImageView alloc] initWith... oh there's no initWithFrame for UIImageView.

Perhaps, someone can explain the process for an image. Do I even need to set the frame size for a UIImageView? I would need to position it.

EDIT:

my new code:

```
UIImageView *posterValue = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,105,175)];
        posterValue.tag = kPosterValueTag;
        [cell.contentView addSubView:posterValue];
        [posterValue release];
```

addSubView is not working for UIImageView. Says UIView may not respond to addSubView

Comment: wait! there is initWithFrame for UIImageView! my mistake. I guess that solves everything?

Comment: Lol, was about to say "ummm UIImageView inherits from UIView, so yes, there is an initWithFrame"

Comment: Yep, the frame is needed for displaying a view correctly.

Comment: You can also use initWithImage:(UIImage *). It makes the frame at the size of your image.

Comment: I guess initWithImage will allow me to skip the tag steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's addSubview not addSubView - case matters.